# How do you solve this problem in colab yolo "darknet Very small path to the image:"

Tags: yolo

I'm training YOLO3. but" Very small path to the image" printed out irregularly. I wonder why the " Very small path to the image" is printed. The training hasn't stopped, but I wonder if this sentence affects the training results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooayn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the "\n" characters in your label or train list. Check your list and remove empty lines. Specially check the end of the list.